# C# & SQL Server : incomplete update (string type)

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I'm trying to update a column with a string and it doesn't update correctly.

I'm displaying the `string` right before the update function and even after it's passed as a parameter (`tip_reparatii`,from the function) it's the same string but it doesn't update in the database.

The update function:

```
public void updateInventar ( int ID_INVENTAR, int ID_CEAS, DateTime data_intrare, string tip_reparatii, string pret, int tip_contact1, int ok_refuse, int tip_contact2, DateTime ok_refuse_date, int ID_STATUS, int ID_LOCALIZARE, DateTime data_iesire, string note, int ID_TEHNICIAN ) {
    if ( IsOnline() ) {
        try {
            string sqlInsertQuery = "UPDATE dbo.Inventar SET data_intrare=@data_intrare, tip_reparatii=@tip_reparatii, pret=@pret, tip_contact1=@tip_contact1, ok_refuse=@ok_refuse, tip_contact2=@tip_contact2, ok_refuse_date=@ok_refuse_date, ID_STATUS=@ID_STATUS, ID_LOCALIZARE=@ID_LOCALIZARE, data_iesire=@data_iesire, note=@note,ID_TEHNICIAN=@ID_TEHNICIAN WHERE ID_INVENTAR=@ID_INVENTAR AND ID_CEAS=@ID_CEAS";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlInsertQuery, DbCon);
            MessageBox.Show(tip_reparatii); //this is the same string and it's correct

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data_intrare", data_intrare);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tip_reparatii", tip_reparatii);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pret", pret);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tip_contact1", tip_contact1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ok_refuse", ok_refuse);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tip_contact2", tip_contact2);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ok_refuse_date", ok_refuse_date);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_STATUS", ID_STATUS);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_LOCALIZARE", ID_LOCALIZARE);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data_iesire", data_iesire);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@note", note);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_TEHNICIAN", ID_TEHNICIAN);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_INVENTAR", ID_INVENTAR);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_CEAS", ID_CEAS);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        } catch ( SqlException e ) {
            MessageBox.Show(null, "Could not Update! " + e.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    } else {
        MessageBox.Show(null, "SQL Connection Throttled!", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

The call code:

```
private void btnActualiser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string tipReparatiiString = "";

    if (this.cblReparatii.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRowView itm in cblReparatii.CheckedItems)
        {  
            tipReparatiiString += itm.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString() + " ";
        }

        MessageBox.Show(tipReparatiiString); //this is correct
        obj.updateInventar(int.Parse(this.cblReparatii.SelectedValue.ToString()), int.Parse(this.cbCeas.SelectedValue.ToString()), this.dtDataIn.Value, tipReparatiiString, this.tbPrix.Text, this.cbPrin.SelectedIndex, this.cbOkRef.SelectedIndex, this.cbPrin2.SelectedIndex, this.dtOkRef.Value, int.Parse(this.cbStatus.SelectedValue.ToString()), int.Parse(this.cbLocatie.SelectedValue.ToString()), this.dtDataOut.Value, this.tbNote.Text, int.Parse(this.cbTehnician.SelectedValue.ToString()));

    }
    else
    {
        //Msg 
    }      
}
```

Both message boxes display the correct string but it doesn't update in the database or it sometimes updates incorrectly(a piece of the string).

We added a `string` manually as a parameter and it worked:

```
obj.updateInventar(int.Parse(this.cblReparatii.SelectedValue.ToString()), 
                   int.Parse(this.cbCeas.SelectedValue.ToString()), 
                   this.dtDataIn.Value, "this works perfectly", 
                   this.tbPrix.Text, this.cbPrin.SelectedIndex, 
                   this.cbOkRef.SelectedIndex, this.cbPrin2.SelectedIndex, 
                   this.dtOkRef.Value, 
                   int.Parse(this.cbStatus.SelectedValue.ToString()),  
                   int.Parse(this.cbLocatie.SelectedValue.ToString()), 
                   this.dtDataOut.Value, this.tbNote.Text, 
                   int.Parse(this.cbTehnician.SelectedValue.ToString()) );
```

The other values update correctly.

Comment: What data type does the debugger how for the `@tip_reparatii` parameter on the `cmd` object? I'd **always** recommend using `Add` over `AddWithValue` and specifying the expected datatype **and length**

Comment: try using a smaller string.  like @RowlandShaw says, I believe for extra long strings you'd need to specify the data type and length for the parameter

Comment: AddWithValue is actually what I would prefer and let the Database do the resolving of the datatype. which would then lead me to ask what is the datatype defined on the sever side sounds like a datatype and or casting issue here

Comment: @Rowland Shaw We did it with `Add` and Intelli said it's deprecated. The datatype of `tip_reparatii` is `nvachar(MAX)` and we tried with `text` type in the database.

Comment: here's an Idea.. why not convert that dynamic query into a stored procedure and test / run it that way ..this would help narrow it down in my opinion

Comment: @AlW The string is fairly small. We tried ("1 2 3 4") manually and it worked and the same string from `tipReparatiiString` it displayed correctly but it didn't update.

Comment: `.Add("@tip_reparatii", tip_reparatii)` *is* depreciated, but `.Add("@tip_reparatii", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = tip_reparatii` is not, and doesn't make the runtime guess at what the server is expecting.

Comment: You should always specify the datatypes and length of your parameters. Don't use the implicit setting of AddWithValue. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @RowlandShaw I tried with what you suggested. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tip_reparatii", tip_reparatii);

Try:

cmd.Parameters.Add("@tip_reparatii",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value=tip_reparatii;

or with a size parameter such as 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@tip_reparatii",SqlDbType.NVarChar,200).Value=tip_reparatii;

You should do this type of add for all your SQL command Parameters.

Comment: I tried with `cmd.Parameters.Add("@tip_reparatii", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tip_reparatii;` then with 200 size and still nothing. It doesn't want to update. The type of the field in the DB is nvarchar(200), tried with nvarchar(MAX) for curiosity and still nothing.  Edit: tried with text type and nope.

Comment: Try using the .ToString().Trim() at the end of tip_reparatii, so cmd.Parameters.Add("@tip_reparatii", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tip_reparatii.ToString().Trim();

Comment: Also change all the .AddWithValues to .Add(parameter,sqlDBType.Type).Value=var;
and see if that helped

Comment: Tried with trim still nothing. Like I said previously I changed `.AddWithValues` to `.Add. This doesn't work either `cmd.Parameters.Add("@tip_reparatii", SqlDbType.NVarChar,300).Value = tip_reparatii.Trim();` Still no solution. Like I said in OP I added a string manually "1 2 3 4" and it inserts in the DB. With the string I try to send as a parameter it doesn't. I display the string I want to insert before the function call and inside the function and it displays correctly. Checked the length of the string and it's correct.

Comment: Instead of adding it manually, Does it update correctly if you set
    string tipReparatiiString = "1 2 3 4";
in your btnActualiser_Click function?

Comment: It doesn't. It must be some sort of conversion problem from `string` to `nvarchar`. But that still makes no sense because `"1 2 3 4"` is also a `string`.

Comment: I copied and pasted exactly what you have, made a database, and ran it on my machine....and it updated as expected...The only thing I have different is the (isOnline) function...I dont know what your function looks like so it is commented out. Also the values I passed, i assigned like this:
int ID_INVENTAR=0;
int ID_CEAS=0; 
DateTime data_intrare=DateTime.Today;; 
string tip_reparatii="1 2 3 4"; 
etc...
because I don't have the other objects in the mock-up.

Comment: We found the problem a few minutes ago. The problem was ID_INVENTAR. It was updating an unexisting record (no error from nowhere). Thank you very much for your effort in helping us. It was updating yesterday because of pure coincidence (ID_INVENTAR) matched what was in the DB.